# background image works in body tag but not in css

Tags: html, css

I tried and searched a lot but I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

When I write in my html file like:

```
<body background="images/background/123.jpg">
```

The background image is shown but when I write the following code in the CSS file it's not:

```
body {
    background-image: url("../images/background/123.jpg");
}
```

Other settings to the image made in CSS do work.

Does anyone has an idea why it is not working in CSS?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: JPG uppercase? linux environment?

Comment: In addition, is that a space after the left arrow on the body tag?

Comment: Are you sure the location is correct? Based on your CSS, the image should be in a sub-folder of the directory where the HTML file lives.

Comment: no its windows environment. does it make a difference when its in uppercase? i also tried with small letters just now

Comment: the space is actually not in there. dreamweaver shows the image in preview so that the directory should be correct

Comment: can you give us a structure of your project then? it seems that it is a relative path issue

Comment: Yes. On the internet, case matters after the domain name.

Comment: thre structure is: com/images/background/123.jpg the index file is lying in the "com" folder

Comment: Remember that paths in CSS files are relative to the location of the CSS file, not the page using it

Comment: oh guys i'm so sorry. dreamweaver didn't show it in browser but when i uploaded it to the webspace it worked

Comment: i'm still newby. thank you all for your fast replies

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the HTML file and the CSS file are in the same directory.
The CSS version had a path `"images/background/123.JPG"`
But the HTML tag version has a path "../images/background/123.JPG"

Considering nothing is wrong with the syntax here, the problem here is definitely the path

Try

```
background-image:url("images/background/123.JPG");
```

Comment: Why? What do you think the problem is that this answer might solve? Throwing inexplicable, or unexplained, guesses at the wall isn't the best way for you to earn reputation points (assuming you have an interest in doing so) or for the OP, or future visitors to the page, learning anything useful.

Comment: @DavidThomas fair enough. I agree just throwing the answer out there does not add to the learning experience of the OP. Thank you for guiding me. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
background-image:url("../images/background/123.jpg");
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: you were using .jpg in html and .JPG in css. That's why.